# How can I use a short code to redirect a URL in Word Press

Tags: php, wordpress, url, woocommerce, shortcode

Currently, when I select an item from a custom menu in WordPress, it takes me to `domain.com/category` when I want to be able to change the URL to `domain.com/shop/category`

The link is set here:

```php
<h5 class="game-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>
```

Here is where I want to redirect the `the_permalink()` to something such as `the_shoplink()` and redirect to the shop URL, not the permalink URL.

I can't change the menu to be the shop page because of the themes custom post type so I'm looking to redirect the post to `the_shoplink()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just redirected the post to the shop page using php.

```php
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
       window.location = "http://www.google.com/"
      </script>';
```